# Pass values from select option to input field and back

Tags: forms, select, input

Just asked another question but i think I need a much simpler solution. 
Therefore i have made this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4EVBL/18/

```
<select name="selection" class="box1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;" multiple>
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
```

Is it possible to have the values (1 and 2) selected in the selected "box" on load, so it is possible to see which ones are selected. And is it possible to have the values of the input field divided by comma, so if one add "3" the value in the input fild will be 1,2,3. Can it also be done so that if you remove the value "2" in the select field the input field will say 1,3 ?

Any tips or help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make a couple of changes to your existing code. To populate the `select` on load, the following will suffice:

```
$(".box1").val($(".box2").val().split(","));
```

which populates `.box1` with an array of values.

Meanwhile, to populate the textbox when the select box changes, use the `.val()` method instead of complicating it with `:selected` selectors and `.text()` methods:

```
$(".box1").change(function () {
    $(".box2").val($(this).val());
});
```

JavaScript will automatically do a `.toString()` of the array into a comma-separated list of selected values.

Comment: Hi Adrian. Thx, that sound easy, is there any way I can make you update the JSFiddle for me, I am not quite sure of how to "mix" it all together and make it work :) 

EDIT: Like so? http://jsfiddle.net/4EVBL/19/